# Offset in fortuitous coincidences in Na22 PET scan

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radioactivity, particle-detectors

I'm doing a PET scan for a Na22 radioactive sample and analysing the fortuitous coincidences. To measure the fortuitous coincidences I put both detectors in a 90º angle and gathered the number of (fortuitous) counts for a fixed time (60s).

By comparing the theoretical model (blue) with the gathered data fit (red) I've noticed a systematic offset not predicted by the model. I looked at the Na22 spectrum and I hypothesize that it has to do with the Compton scattering - but can't explain it further. What do you think may be the source of this offset?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be nice for the readers if you have more context to the figures presented here.

Comment: What do you mean by "fortuitous coincidences"? This is not a term I am familiar with. Is this another word for "accidentals", where each detector is hit by photons from uncorrelated events? Similarly, what is tau in the first graph? I interpret it to be the length of the time window in which you are forming coincidences (which then should have accidentals scale linearly)

Comment: Also it would be useful to know what kind of gamma detectors you are using, if you have access to the energy spectra, and what kind of resolution you have.